# Restricting Page Templates or Excluding paths with RegEx

Tags: regex, aem

I am working on an AEM 6.0 project and I have a handful of templates with the allowedPath property currently set for /content(/.*)? Later I was asked to create an events template that would only be shown to authors in the /content/sitename/events node. I have it's allowedPath property set to /content/sitename/events(/.*)? so it only shows in the events node. That part works as expected.

The issue I am having is that I need to hide the other main site templates when creating pages at the events node and only show authors the events template.

I started working out a regular expression to exclude the events node in the other templates. It's close but not 100%. Hoping someone can help point me in the right direction.

Here is the closest solution I have so far:

```
/content(([^events])*)?
```

Currently, it matches the parent and child pages correctly, however siblings also get excluded too and that is where the problem is. I don't want to exclude sibling pages in the regex, only events and lower.

Bonus question: Can templates successfully be excluded in this way? or is there a better way?  I read over the docs here: http://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/templates.html but could not determine how to disallow from specific nodes.  I wished AEM had a disallowedPaths property.

For giggles, here are some of the variations to the regex I tried but they seemed more problematic than the above.

```
/content/(([^events])*)? 
/content(([^/events])/.*)? 
/content(([^events])*)?
```

Comment: Okay, I am making some progress. 
New expression looks like this.

`/content/sitename(/(?!event).*)?`

I only have one edge case where the template does not appear properly. For example I am matching "event" so pages created with a name like event-calendar also get excluded.

See demo: http://regexr.com/3atrt

Comment: Take a look at this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905975/aem-how-to-restrict-a-template-from-showing-in-a-certain-path It might help :)