# AEM - How to restrict a template from showing in a certain path

Tags: regex, aem

I wonder if someone has achieved what I'll post here. In order to allow a template to be created under a certain path, there is a flag `allowedPaths` that receives a regex.

So, if I want my template `"test"` to appear only under `/content/www/xx/xx/test-templates` and child elements, I can do this:

```
/content/www/.*/.*/test-templates(/.*)?
```

But what if I want to make the opposite? I want the template `"test"` to appear in every `/content/www/xx/xx/` node and beyond, EXCEPT `/content/www/xx/xx/test-templates` and children?

I have tried several ways but no luck so far. Do you have some hint regarding this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this flavor supports regex, but you can try `^(?!/content/www/[^/]*/[^/]*/test-templates)/content/www/[^/]*/[^/]*(/.*)` or `(?!/content/www/[^/]*/[^/]*/test-templates)/content/www/[^/]*/[^/]*(/.*)`

Comment: Checking it right now. I think this is a very good solution! I'll put results here in a few.

Comment: http://regexr.com/3ckfm seems that is almost almost working! :) it is still excluding /content/www/us/en/test-templates-calendar and /content/www/us/en/test-templates-calendar/ which should be accepted.

Comment: Use [`^(?!/content/www/[^/]*/[^/]*/test-templates(?:/|$))/content/www/[^/]*/[^/]*(/.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/eR8dZ6/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always restrict a more generic pattern with a lookahead. Here is an expression that should work for you:

```
^(?!/content/www/[^/]*/[^/]*/test-templates(?:/|$))/content/www/[^/]*/[^/]*(/.*)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eR8dZ6/1).

- `^` - matches the start of string
- `(?!/content/www/[^/]*/[^/]*/test-templates(?:/|$))` - makes sure the next substring is not `/content/www/<some_node>/<some_node>/test-templates`, followed by the end of string (`$`) or `/`
- `/content/www/[^/]*/[^/]*(/.*)` - matches `/content/www/<some_node>/<some_node>` followed with optional `/` and zero or more characters other than a newline

Comment: I thought it could be shortened, but it did not work then :(

Comment: Works like a charm dude! Thank you very much! :D